# how can i do it without switch case loop(counter for example)

Tags: c

I wrote this program that asks for the number of characters wish is alphabet in a single line and then calculates the possible configurations through that number..but the options are limited..so how can I make the selections unlimited in a domaine  like for exp : you have maximum 4 characters in a line?`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    int Nb_Alpha,P_Kida = 1,i,j,k,h,Power = 1,nb,P_lvl,counter = 1;
    printf("enter the number of alphabet in one line :\t\n");
    scanf("%d",&Nb_Alpha);
    for(i=1;i<=Nb_Alpha;i++)//this is the Exponent made by me
    {
        P_Kida *= 26;
     }
  
        switch(Nb_Alpha)
        {
            case 1: 
            {
                
                for(i=65;i<=90;i++)
                        {
                            printf("%c\n",i);
                        }
            
             }  
            break;
             
             case 2 : {
                
                printf("Double probabilytis !\n");
                for(i=65;i<=90;i++)
                {
                    for(j=65;j<=90;j++)
                    {
                        printf("%c%c\n",i,j);
                    }
                }
             }
             break;
            
            case 3: 
            {
                    printf("Triple probabilytis !\n");
                    for(i=65;i<=90;i++)
                    {
                        for(j=65;j<=90;j++)
                        {
                          for(k=65;k<=90;k++)
                          {
                                printf("%c%c%c\n",i,j,k);
                          }
                        }
                    }
            
            }
            break;
            
                case 4: 
            {
                    printf("Quadra probabilytis !\n");
                    for(i=65;i<=90;i++)
                    {
                        for(j=65;j<=90;j++)
                        {
                          for(k=65;k<=90;k++)
                          {
                            for(h=65;h<=90;h++)
                            {
                                printf("%c%c%c%c\n",i,j,k,h);
                              }
                                
                          }
                        }
                    }
            
            }
            break;
            
        }
        
        
        
            
        printf("that is the %d probabilytis that u can make with %d alphabets\n",P_Kida,Nb_Alpha);
    return 0;
}`
```

Comment: i have deleted one line now the code is much clear.

Comment: what i meant by unlimited selections that each time the Nb_Alpha increase by one i need to increase the for loop's by one so the problem is how can i know how much loop variables i need to declare

Comment: Add a default: case to the switch (doing nothing) For "unlimited" length: use recursion.

Comment: okey i see that "recursion" term is the solution, thank you @wildplasser now i'm convinced ^^.

Comment: BTW: `for(j= 'A' ; j<= 'Z'; j++)` is easier to read. (and please omit the extra braces after the `case:` )

Comment: i wish teachers would stop teaching that they can use system("pause") to pause a program, it is risky since it is so easy to change in the binary.

Comment: @AndersK didn't get you ^^' ???

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: (the compiler does not care) Please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: OT: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 26, 65, 90  'magiic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using an `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names then using those meaningful names throughout the code,

Comment: OT: please follow the axiom:  *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: OT: When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.   ( for `gcc`,at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` ) note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results.

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%d",&Nb_Alpha);`  There are many ways the user can cause this statement to fail.  ALways check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  Suggest: `if( scanf("%d",&Nb_Alpha) != 1 ) { fprintf( stderr, "scanf for ... failed\n" ); clleanup then exit( EXIT_FAILURE );}`    Also, what is the user only enters a '\n' (or similar)?   Never trust the user to do the expected action.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to use recursion.

For instance:

```
#define MAX 32

void rec(unsigned int nb, char* s, size_t len)
{
    if (nb == 0)
    {
        puts(s);
        return;
    }
    
    for(int i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++)
    {
        s[len] = i;
        rec(nb - 1, s, len + 1);
    }
    s[len] = '\0';
}


void foo(unsigned int nb)
{
    assert(nb <= MAX);
    char x[MAX + 1] = "";
    
    for(int i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++)
    {
        x[0] = i;
        rec(nb - 1, x, 1);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    foo(6);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you that is more advanced than my level at c ^^' i don't even know what is recursion function(yes i will get info about it as  soon as i can) thank you again but i'm searching for logical solution with math and without predefined function(if there is one).

Comment: and in this function void rec() i didn't understand how can we use the name of function inside of the same function , like what you did :      `void rec(int nb, char* s, char c)
{
    char x[MAX];
    sprintf(x, "%s%c", s, c);
    
    if (nb <= 0)
    {
        printf("%s\n", x);
        return;
    }
    
    for(int i = 65; i <= 90; i++)
    {
        rec(nb - 1, x, i);
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Recursion seems like an overkill here. Think of your configurations as numbers.

How would you list all the k-digit numbers? Obviously, start with `0...0`, and increment until it becomes `9...9`.

Your problem is exactly the same. Start with `a...a`, and increment until it becomes `z...z`. Now the question is how to increment a string? Same way as a number. If the last character is not yet `z`, increment it; if it is make it `a`, and try to increment the previous one, etc.

I hope you can take it from here.

Comment: thank you user5897 if i start from what you write  i think i'm gonna have the solution for the unlimited selections.